# Clocks on Air-gapped, Offline Computers

Tags: mainnet

What risks (security-related or otherwise) may potentially inaccurate clocks--that is, clocks that do not synchronize with an Internet time server--on air-gapped, offline computers used to sign transactions create for Cardano mainnet?

Answer (score 2):

Time plays no role in Cardano transactions, so the computer that signs transactions doesn't need a notion of time.

You can however specify a range of slots in which your transaction is valid. (But transaction building, which is distinct from signing, is something you would usually do on an online computer, so you can also easily determine the UTxO IDs to use as inputs.)